# jquery UI autocomplete dropdown not displaying and gives error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is my html

```
<input id="patient_name" name="patient" rows="5" cols="20">
```

This is the header that I have in the html where

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/template/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/template/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/template/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/template/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/template/additional.methods.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/template/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/template/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
```

And this is the script for the autocomplete

```
$("#patient_name").autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
    source:window.peerjson,
    focus: function(event, ui) {

        $( "#patient_name" ).val(ui.item.firstname);
        return false;
      },
        select: function(event, ui) {

            $( "#patient_name" ).val(ui.item.firstname+" "+ui.item.lastname); //ui.item is your object from the array
            return false;
        }

    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    console.log(item);
      return $( "<li></li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.firstname + " " + item.lastname + "</a>")
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

After running this and type something it gives me error in chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object [object Object] is not a function jquery-ui.js:6
t.widget._search jquery-ui.js:6
e.isFunction.l.(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:6
t.widget.search jquery-ui.js:6
e.isFunction.l.(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:6
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:6
i
```

The value is there in json. But somehow its not showing up.

Comment: upon first guess/look, I think your error points to the line `source:window.peerjson`, but I don't know what `peerjson` is, so I can't tell you for sure. Also, why are you adding methods to the global? It's just not a "suggested" practice. (I don't like the term "bad practice", as anything is possible)

Comment: In your autocomplete function, `source: window.peerjson` is not a valid option - it has to be array, function, or string. See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: peerjson is the json its an array of elements. its a global variable. its updated on window load.

Comment: And since @djf beat me to listing the link, I'll point out, if it's a function, you must do the filtering for the return. "*This data should be filtered based on the provided term*"

Comment: It can't be an array of "elements". If Array, then it should be either an array of *Strings* |OR| and Array of objects specifically written as `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]` Each object must have "label" and "value" keys

Comment: And I fibbed a little (unintentional, was moving to much and too fast through different things). If the "label" key is not provided, then the "value" will be used for label as well, automagically!

Comment: it seems there is something wrong with environment. this works in jsfiddle. I don't understand why it dosen't work in my environment.